# .msc spy BluePrism

Tags: spy, blueprism

Is it possible to launch/attach .msc programs like "services.msc" in blue prism, cause i've been trying to do so for a while, but I fail everytime.

If it's not possible, is there any other way ?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Yes this is possible.  I use RDP examples all the time.  Most .msc apps start up as one application and then add a bunch of overlays.  As such you often have to reattach to the program after the overlay has been loaded.

See: https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B1sLfjzLJH48Ml9veXAyeUR5VG8

Comment: may I know how did you attached the putty mainframe to blueprism, i mean what provider type did you use ?

Comment: It has been a while... Blue Prism has a list of MF emulators supported out of the box.  The Putty was just linked/spied as a Windows application.